# Can't style @mui Avatar icon with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm playing around with styled-components and having troubles working with material-ui. So thats the code:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import ChatIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Chat";
import MoreVertIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoreVert";
import { Avatar} from "@mui/material";

function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Header>
        <UserAvatar className={"override"} />
        <IconsContainer>
          <IconButton>
            <ChatIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton>
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </IconsContainer>
      </Header>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;

const Container = styled.div``;
const Header = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 80px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid whitesmoke;
`;
const UserAvatar = styled(Avatar)`
  height: 60px;
`;
const IconsContainer = styled.div`;
```

The styled div is working completely fine, but when I import 'Avatar' from @mui and try to add some styling named UserAvatar, it is completely ignoring what I'm writing down.

Answer (score 0):

I think that with mui they have their own version of `styled` for styled components. https://mui.com/system/styled/

It appears they want you to use it rather than styled-components

```ts
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const CustomButton = styled(Button)({
  // your custom styles go here
}) as typeof Button;
```

see the import from `import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';;`